# Not able to plot a function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So I am having a problem plotting an if statement function. Could someone tell me where i am going wrong? The code follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 



#x-axis

x_1 = np.arange(-20,20,0.001)

#defining the function
def h(x):
    """
    input: x \in R
    oupit: h(x) defined above in R. 
    """
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return np.sin(x)/x

def g(x):
    """
    input: x \in R
    oupit: g(x) defined above in R. 
    """
    return np.cos(x)

#drawing the function

plt.plot(x_1,h(x_1),label = r"$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$",color="red")
plt.legend()
plt.plot(x_1,g(x_1),label = r"$\cos(x)$",color="blue")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(linestyle="dotted")
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
#plt.savefig('img231.pdf')
plt.show()
```

The main problem is probably in the line with `plt.plot(x_1,h(x_1))`.  Any answers are appreciated:)~ Thanks, Y

Comment: x_1 is a numpy array so you can't use `if x == 0:` . Use a loop to iterate through the array and check every element using `if x == 0:` or use some method from numpy module

Comment: `if x.any() == 0`, or `if x.all() == 0` might be what you want

Comment: To write an `if`-test in numpy, you need `np.where`: `def h(x): with np.errstate(divide='ignore'): return np.where(x == 0, 1, np.sin(x)/x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write an `if`-test in numpy, you need `np.where`: `np.where(x == 0, 1, np.sin(x)/x)`.
This still will write a warning for division by zero, which can be suppressed using `with np.errstate(divide='ignore')`.

Also note that `np.arange(-20, 20, 0.001)` generates `40000` values, which is quite high compared to the number of pixels on a screen (an even compared to the dots on a printer). Using `np.linspace()` you have easier control over the number of points used. Using too many points can unnecessarily slow down calculations and plotting.

Calling `plt.legend()` twice can be a bit confusing. The second call will remove the first legend.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_1 = np.linspace(-20, 20, 1000)

def h(x):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        return np.where(x == 0, 1, np.sin(x) / x)

def g(x):
    return np.cos(x)

plt.plot(x_1, h(x_1), label=r"$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$", color="crimson")
plt.plot(x_1, g(x_1), label=r"$\cos(x)$", color="cornflowerblue")
plt.grid(linestyle="dotted")
plt.ylabel("$f(x)$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for a great response! Very thorough. ^_^

Comment: could one use np.where for more than if statement?

Comment: You'll need to nest the `np.where`'s. Like `np.where(x>0, np.where(y>0, 1, 2), 3)`